# Horizontal slider/carosel that does not cause a rough vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to recreate a horizontal slider similar to one on Spotify or Netflix that moves when a button is clicked. [Netflix Slider/Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umxu6.jpg) & [Spotify Slider/Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGsaH.png). They are prevalent in many different websites such as Amazon and others. But even so, I have had a terribly difficult time finding anything similar to it. I saw a video on Youtube ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maNqKIfk3ds)) but on this one, the arrows remain during the sliding animation. Another solution I found was to just make a horizontal scroll using the `overflow-x` property in CSS which produces a slider but without the buttons so settled with that. This would be the end of the story but for some reason, it causes a rough vertical scroll when I'm scrolling down my website.

This is my website code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.section1 {
  height: 92vh;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 30px 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.navButtonL {
  background-color: #555555;
}

.navButtonS {
  background-color: #8b008b;
}

.navButtonL,
.navButtonS {
  padding: 7.5px 14px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.navButtonL a,
.navButtonS a {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.showcaseTitle {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #555555;
}

.showcaseTitle h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.showcaseSummary {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.showcaseSummary p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.section2 {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}


/*
.slider:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
    filter: brightness(90%);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}*/

.sliders {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.sliders::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sliderTitle {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: #8b008b;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 37px;
}

.sliderTitle h4 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.slider {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 25px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sliderImage {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.sliderName {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #555555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.sliderQuote {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
  <title>ShowGauge - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav5</a></li>
            <li class="navButtonL"><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
            <li class="navButtonS"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showcaseTitle">
      <h1>Showcase</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="showcaseSummary">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="1-2Line">
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="sliderTitle">
      <h4>Slider 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sliders">
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderTitle">
      <h4>Slide 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sliders">
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderTitle">
      <h4>Slider 3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sliders">
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://sumaleeboxinggym.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Generic-Profile-1600x1600.png" class='sliderImage'>
        <h2 class="sliderName">Slide</h2>
        <h4 class="sliderQuote">"Slide Desc."</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm looking for a solution ideally in pure HTML, CSS, and/or JS I can add to my code unlike something like Slick Carousels or an external file I have to add from the internet. JQuery will also be welcomed but pure HTML, CSS, and/or JS is ideal. (Sorry for the long and bulky HTML file I was planning on shortening it by using a for loop in Django Jinja.)

(If there is anything I can do to assist in solving the problem please tell me.)

Thank you so much to anyone who attempts to solve my problem!